# Ionic / Android 8+: Audio stops playing after about 5 mins when screen is locked

Tags: android, ionic-framework, audio, background, android-8.0-oreo

My app plays music using the *cordova-plugin-media* plugin. *cordova-plugin-background-mode* is handling the background tasks.

This block of code is present in my app.component.ts:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.backgroundMode.setDefaults({
      title: 'MyMusicApp',
        text: 'Android 8 problem!',
        resume: true,
        hidden: true,
        silent: true
    });
}
```

And when the media player provider component receives a ‘play’ command, it calls:

```
this.backgroundMode.enable();
```

On Android 6 and 7, the audio nicely plays in the background when the screen is locked. However, on Android 8, every single time, when the screen is locked (or times out), after about 5 minutes, the background audio is cut off.

From what I read, Android 8+ is using a new implementation to handle 3rd party apps that keep active or are using resources in the background. The solution above was an attempt at solving this cut-off problem, but it does not seem to help…

Would anyone be able to offer help with this? How can the background audio best be handled on Android 8?

Comment: Have a look here https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues. They are reporting 5-min-crash-issues on Android O as well. So `cordova-plugin-background-mode` is your problem, not `cordova-plugin-media`.

Comment: Its not working on android 8+ devices.

Comment: I have the same problem, Android 8+ and 9+

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my app. As of today, per my experience, the original [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) does not work with target API level 26+ (Android 8+). Lots of people forked the project to make their own fixes, it is very much possible some of them work.

As for me, I opted to use another plugin: [cordova-plugin-foreground-service](https://github.com/DavidBriglio/cordova-plugin-foreground-service). It works **only** for Android 8+, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I can fix the issue using this code:

```
    if (this.isCordova) {
        // play the file
            this.backgroundMode.enable();
            this.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ title: "title", text: 'title'});
            this.backgroundMode.on('activate').subscribe(() => {
                this.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
            });


    }
```

and adding this on config.xml:

```
    <config-file parent="./" target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    </config-file>
```